# How do you include a JS module with TideSDK?

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile, tidesdk

With Titanium Mobile you can do include modules with:

```
ASW = Ti.include('./modules/amazon').load();
```

This fails with TideSDK. I've looked and looked and found nothing! Most likely I'm missing something obvious. Help!?

Comment: is this an iphone buit module or js module

Comment: In this case, I'm trying to take an Amazon AWS module that was built for Titanium Mobile, and get it running on TideSDK. But I also would like to be able to require my own modules for a more organized app

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge, modules are accessed using require function. And for Ti.include I am not sure.
So try with require function as below:

```
var ASW = require('./modules/amazon');
```

That's it. Hope it will help

Comment: Unfortunately, require is not defined.

Comment: This is not possible, Paste your code. It works fine. I have used it more than 20times.

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark it as answered so that others could get help from it.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Require works dandy in Node but not in TideSDK.